# Circuit Analysis Q's

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

When looking for the node voltages of the following circuit below I was wondering why we are not able to get the correct answer for node voltage V1 by solving the following way.

---

I1 = V2/30 = 100/30 = 3.33 A

I2 = 15 - 3.33 = 11.667 A

11.667 = (V1 - Vx)/10 = (V1 - 700)/10

V1 = 816.67 V

---

Though when doing KCL at node V1 I get the correct answer for V1 = 583.33 V

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram with your annotations, plus my addition using the passive sign convention for the resistors. (The more \$+\$ end of a resistor is where the current arrow enters the resistor and the more \$-\$ end of a resistor is where the current arrow exits the resistor.)

\$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\$[image]

Your approach and solution for \$v_2\$ is correct. \$v_2=100\:\text{V}\$.

So, \$v_{_\text{X}}=700\:\text{V}\$.

It's only at this point where you make mistakes. Since the more positive end of the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor is at \$v_{_\text{X}}\$, the more negative end of that resistor ***must*** be less than \$700\:\text{V}\$. Not greater. So \$v_1\$ must be less than \$700\:\text{V}\$.

The current in the \$10\:\Omega\$/\$50\:\Omega\$ branch must be \$\frac{700\:\text{V}}{10\:\Omega+50\:\Omega}\$ and pointing exactly as you showed \$i_2\$. So, \$i_2=\frac{700\:\text{V}}{60\:\Omega}\$. That will cause a voltage ***drop*** across the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor of \$v_{_\text{DROP}}=10\:\Omega\cdot i_2=116\frac23\:\text{V}\$. So \$v_1\$ will be that much ***lower*** than \$700\:\text{V}\$, or \$v_1=v_{_\text{X}}-v_{_\text{DROP}}=700\:\text{V}-116\frac23\:\text{V}=583\frac13\:\text{V}\$.

You used \$v_1-v_{_\text{x}}\$. The current arrow implied by that subtraction has the arrow pointing from the left to the right. You should have used \$v_{_\text{x}}-v_1\$, instead, so that the current arrow was consistent with how you drew \$i_2\$.

That's the only mistake you made, I think.